# opendaylight shards are missing in Nitrogen SR3 load

Tags: karaf, opendaylight

we are using nitrogen SR3 package and we have customized 2 node cluster. After soaking the cluster for 2 or 3 days. we noticed NoShardleaderException. We also checked through JMX  and noticed "default-"config and "default-operational" shards in Distributed Data store doesn't exist.
Can you please let us know the possible reasons for shards missing suddenly??

### update :

following exceptions are noticed in karaf.log

018-07-09 12:31:11,000 | ERROR | lt-dispatcher-15  | 219 - com.typesafe.akka.slf4j - 2.4.7 | Slf4jLogger$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1 | **Failed to persist event type [org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.raft.ReplicatedLogImplEntry] with sequence number [13058670] for persistenceId [member-1-shard-default-config].
akka.pattern.CircuitBreaker$$anon$1: Circuit Breaker Timed out.**
2018-07-09 12:31:11,000 | ERROR | lt-dispatcher-15  | 219 - com.typesafe.akka.slf4j - 2.4.7 | Slf4jLogger$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1 | Failed to persist event type [org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.raft.ReplicatedLogImplEntry] with sequence number [13058670] for persistenceId [member-1-shard-default-config].
akka.pattern.CircuitBreaker$$anon$1: Circuit Breaker Timed out.

2018-07-19 02:03:14,687 | WARN  | t-dispatcher-172  | 505 - org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore - 1.6.3 | ActorContext$4 | broadcast failed to send message CloseTransactionChain to shard default:  {}
**org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.exceptions.NoShardLeaderException:** Shard member-2-shard-default-config currently has no leader. Try again later.
    at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.shardmanager.ShardManager.createNoShardLeaderException(ShardManager.java:955)[505:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:1.6.3]
    at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.shardmanager.ShardManager.onShardNotInitializedTimeout(ShardManager.java:787)[505:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:1.6.3]
    at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.shardmanager.ShardManager.handleCommand(ShardManager.java:254)[505:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:1.6.3]
    at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.common.actor.AbstractUntypedPersistentActor.onReceiveCommand(AbstractUntypedPersistentActor.java:44)[498:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-clustering-commons:1.6.3]
    at akka.persistence.UntypedPersistentActor.onReceive(PersistentActor.scala:170)[322:com.typesafe.akka.persistence:2.4.20]
    at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.common.actor.MeteringBehavior.apply(MeteringBehavior.java:104)[498:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-clustering-commons:1.6.3]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell$$anonfun$become$1.applyOrElse(ActorCell.scala:544)[317:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.4.20]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)[317:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.4.20]
    at akka.persistence.UntypedPersistentActor.akka$persistence$Eventsourced$$super$aroundReceive(PersistentActor.scala:168)[322:com.typesafe.akka.persistence:2.4.20]
    at akka.persistence.Eventsourced$$anon$1.stateReceive(Eventsourced.scala:727)[322:com.typesafe.akka.persistence:2.4.20]
    at akka.persistence.Eventsourced$class.aroundReceive(Eventsourced.scala:183)[322:com.typesafe.akka.persistence:2.4.20]
    at akka.persistence.UntypedPersistentActor.aroundReceive(PersistentActor.scala:168)[322:com.typesafe.akka.persistence:2.4.20]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)[317:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.4.20]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)[317:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.4.20]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)[317:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.4.20]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)[317:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.4.20]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)[317:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.4.20]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)[616:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.11.12.v20171031-225310-b8155a5502]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)[616:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.11.12.v20171031-225310-b8155a5502]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)[616:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.11.12.v20171031-225310-b8155a5502]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)[616:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.11.12.v20171031-225310-b8155a5502]

Comment: We have noticed following exceptions in karaf;log.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Shard actor threw an exception and akka killed the actor. Look for exceptions in the log.